# is it legitimate to t-test between statistics of a bootstrap?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, bootstrap, independence

say I have two samples $x_1$ and $x_2$ and a function which calculates a statistic out of each sample, denotes as $f(x)$.

I would like to test the significance of the difference $f(x_1)-f(x_2)$.

A common (wrong?) procedure would be to bootstrap (with replacement) the two samples and calculate $f$ for each bootstrap fold. In this case, this returns $f_1 = f(\text{bootstrap}(x_1))$ and $f_2 = f(\text{bootstrap}(x_2))$.

Why is it legitimate to use t-test to test the difference in mean between $f_1$ and $f_2$? (I believe it is incorrect)

I ask this because the samples are not truly independent. For example, consider the extreme case where $x_1$ is of size 1. In this case all the bootstrap folds will produce the same outcome. Therefore, if one would increase number of bootstrap fold, the difference will always become significant. So, the significance of the test depends on the number of bootstrap folds which is something which is not very appealing.

What is the right way to do this test?

Comment: A t-test is only appropriate for something that has a t distribution, which commonly comes from a situation where an underlying variable has a normal distribution and we're estimating it's mean and variance simultaneously, so the estimated mean has a t distribution.  Depending on what f is I don't see why you would expect it to have a t distribution.  But I don't think that's the point of your question is it?  Perhaps you could clarify?

Comment: Yeah, I know t-test assume normality. But say that f is mean, so according to central limit, it will be distributed in a normal way if I have enough samples. BUT the samples are re-sampled by bootstrapping so these are not really independent samples. I am trying to ask if the IID (Independent and identically distributed) holds in bootstrapping.